# Импорт файла из облака в модуле python DocxTemplate

Tags: python, python-docx

Как использовать в качестве шаблона файл, находящийся в облачном хранилище?

```
from docx_template import DocxTemplate

doc = DocxTemplate("https://example.com/my_template.docx")
context = { 'name': 'Ivan', 'company': 'My_Corp' }
doc.render(context)
doc.save("result.docx")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, тут поможет библиотека requests, например так:

```
import requests

url = "https://example.com/my_template.docx"
response = requests.get(url)
open("my_template.docx", "wb").write(response.content)
```

Далее примените загруженный файла из облака в качестве шаблона вот так:

```
from docx_template import DocxTemplate

doc = DocxTemplate("my_template.docx")
context = { 'name': 'Ivan', 'company': 'My_Corp' }
doc.render(context)
doc.save
```

Comment: Большое вам спасибо, помогло!